# Solve for unknown interest rate in accumulated amount

Tags: python, iteration, sympy, solver

Hi I am looking for a way to iterate some value with an unknown.
There are 18 cashflows (cf_1 to cf_18) and their corresponding accumulate periods (t1 to t18), stored in 2 lists. I wish to equate the sum of the accumulated amounts (in terms of the unknown interest rate i) to 500000, and solve for this i.

The formula is: 500000 = accumulated value = cf1 * (1+i)^t1 +...+ cf_18 * (1+i)^t18. I could think of using sympy solver:

```
solve(cf1 * (1+i)**t1 +...+ cf_18 * (1+i)**t18 - 500000, i)
```

to solve for i. But apparently for loop can not take this unknown i. So what else can I do beside type out the whole 18 expressions?

This is the data and what I have tried:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol

i = Symbol('i')

cashflow = [13000,
12500,
12000,
11500,
11000,
10500,
10000,
9500,
9000,
8500,
8000,
7500,
7000,
6500,
6000,
5500,
5000,
4500,]

years_accum = [22.75,
22.5,
20.5,
20,
19.25,
19,
18.75,
12,
10.25,
10,
9.75,
9,
8.5,
8,
7.5,
5,
3.5,
3.25,]

for cf in cashflow:
    for yr in years_accum:
        S_t = sum(cf* (1+i)^yr)
        print(S_t)
solve(S_t - 500000, i)
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your double loop is incorrect since for each cash flow it adds all the years. I would have done

```
>>> eq = sum([cf*(1+i)**yr for cf,yr in zip(cashflow, years_accum)]) - 500000
```

But to see this in a loop it could be

```
>>> S_t = 0
>>> for cf, yr in zip(cashflow, years_accum):
...    S_t = S_t + cf*(1+i)**yr

>>> eq = S_t - 500000
```

Now to solve...`solve` would be good if we expect a simple answer (from a relatively simple equation). Since this is highly non-linear `nsolve` (for numerical-solutions) is a better choice:

```
>>> nsolve(eq, 0)  # assume i is close to 0
0.0747836528616713
```

Comment: wow thanks for the solution! so using zip() will assign cf to yr for each index 1 to 18?

Comment: like the teeth on a zipper when zipped...as long as the lists are the same length you will get one from each argument in "zip" in the order they are listed. You can try it in an interactive session (or at live.sympy.org), e.g. `list(zip((1,2,3),"abc"))`